# Themeroller theme isn't rendering any of the attributes I added upon download

Tags: jquery, themes, themeroller, jquery-ui-theme

Is there a hidden "save changes" button I'm missing? Even the example html page included in the zip file doesn't display added attributes when opened. I really like how easy Themeroller is to use(i.e. drag and drop) but I would like it a lot more if I could actually use what I created with it.

Comment: You need to click on the *Downlaod Theme* button that is on the ThemeRoller page, below the text *roll your own* (left hand side).